# Colouring histogram splits it up

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I add an outline colour to my histogram, and fill in the colours it looks like this:
[image]

Here's the code that I am using:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.character(cyl), log(hp), fill = as.character(cyl))) + 
    geom_col(colour=1,alpha = 0.75) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "red", "blue"))
```

How can I remove the horizontal lines for each plot so it remains as a single block with one colour? When I remove `colour=1` I get what I'm after, but I need the black colour outlines for each block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `stat_summary` instead, and making use of `fun = "sum"`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.character(cyl))) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = log(hp), fill = as.character(cyl)), fun = "sum", geom = "bar", colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Apart from the mere technical solution @Gnueghoidune helpfully provided, the undesired appearance of your initial plot hints that there is an underlying conceptual issue: you plot the sum of each car's logarithmised power (which is not the logarithm of the sum) per category "cylinders". What is the viewer of this plot to conclude from this information about the difference between cars of different cylinder count? Or between car brands? Or anything? ;-)